# increase value in an array by index variable with mongoose mongodb nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of numbers :

```
readersNum : {type: [Number], default: []},
```

I would like to increase the value placed in the **indexVariable** by 1.

this works :

```
Posts.update({"readerID":readerID},{$inc:{"readersNum.0":1}},{upsert:true,safe:true},
              function(err){
                  console.log(err);
              });
```

but the problem is i the value is not in a specific(constant) index it is a variable.. assuming the index variable is `indexVariable` and not 0, how should i increase it?

I tried also this :

```
Posts.findOne({"readerID":readerID },['readersNum'],function(err, readerID){
    readerID.readersNum[indexVariable] = readerID.readersNum[indexVariable]+1;
    try { 
        Posts.save(readerID,function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR while saving reader num: " + err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('saved reader num successfully');           

        }
        });
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log("ERROR while saving reader num: " + e);
    }
    });
```

executing the code above prints the changed value in the console and "saved reader num successfully" but the value in the database stays the same!
I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what am i doing wrong. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you know the index you could do this:

```
var update = {};

update['readersNum.' + index] = 1; // update now has property like `readersNum.3`

Posts.update({"readerID":readerID},{$inc: update},{upsert:true,safe:true}, function(err){ console.log(err); });
```